# Convert this Equation for Random

Tags: random, tcl, equation

I want to convert this equation "`( rand() % ( max-min ) ) + min;`" from C++ to the TCL/TK to us it in ns2...I hope if there is anyone can help me.

My Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The expression can't be translated directly, as Tcl's `rand()` returns floating point numbers (in the range 0.0 to 1.0) unlike C++'s `rand()`, which is returning an integer. But a pretty much *moral* equivalent is this:

```
expr { int(rand() * ($max - $min)) + $min }
```

We can wrap this into a little procedure to make it even easier to use (it's just like writing a helper function in C++):

```
proc randInRange {min max} {
    return [expr { int(rand() * ($max - $min)) + $min }]
}

# Example of calling it and using the result:
puts [randInRange 1 10]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Donal, But why we can not use (%), due to in the Equation it used mode divide (%) rather than multiplication.

Comment: Because Tcl's `rand()` will return a floating point number between `0.0` and `1.0`, while C's `rand()` will return an integer.

Comment: Ok...Thanks for your answer and effort.